# KOMA Script: Why does footsepline=false influence the header margin?

Tags: header-footer, margins, koma-script

In the following snippet one can observe unexpected behavior (at least to me)

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\KOMAoptions{%
    headinclude,
    %footsepline=false
}
\recalctypearea
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
    \chapter{bla}
    \section{blub}
    \lipsum[1-20]
\end{document}
```

The option `headinclude` includes the head to the text body, as expected. However, an additional option `footsepline=false` cancels the `headinclude` option and results in a way too small header margin. Interestingly `headinclude` remains, if the option `footsepline=true` is given.

How is this behavior explained?

**EDIT:** Interestingly the order of the options matters in this particular question. If `footsepline=false` is defined before `headinclude` it does not affect the header margin.

Comment: The supposed reason for KOMA was to create more beautiful documents based on theoretical formulas for beauty.

Comment: The bug has been fixed. With [current pre-release 3.23.2606](http://www.komascript.de/current) `footsepline=false` does not longer change `headinclude` (but `footinclude` to `false` which is already the default). Thank you for reporting the bug.

Comment: @Schweinebacke: Thanks for the clarifying comment. If you write the very same in an answer, I would be glad to mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It was indeed a bug in KOMA-Script since v3.20. In `typearea` option `footsepline` has changed the setting of option `headinclude` instead of `footinclude`.

The bug has been fixed in [pre-release 3.23.2606](http://www.komascript.de/current). See the [German release information for KOMA-Script 3.22](http://www.komascript.de/node/2058) or [the change itself](https://sourceforge.net/p/koma-script/code/2606/).